# show text from a Rmd file using purl function in another Rmd file

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a Rmd file with some chunks and some text. How can I add the output (including text) in from that file to another Rmd file, calling the first one with purl or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. The better approach, I believe, is to create a "child" Rmd page which is conditionally executed. I use this regularly to minimize the amount of report code I maintain. You don't provide a code example, but here is a process in one of my reports which executes two different Rmd's depending on the the condition:

````
```{r conditional, child = if (override == "report") 'leaflet_child.Rmd' else 'footer.Rmd'} 
```
````

As far as your perl code, I would place that in one of the child .Rmd's to be executed if condition==T. Also, note that the child page execution chunk should do that and *only* that: execute one or another .Rmd. If you add additional commands in that chunk it will throw warnings.

These conditions can also be passed via commandArgs, as with this example from my project make file which passes the "now" argument, which then conditionally executes certain Rmd files:

```
Rscript $(R_OPTS) -e "rmarkdown::render('putyourscripthere.Rmd')" now
```

This is picked up within the Rmd via something like this, which sets a default value in the event of a null commandArg:

```
# Command arguments
if(length(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)>0)) {
      override <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE) 
  } else {
      override <- "report" 
}
```

Another approach which is much "hacky-er" is to use sed or awk to extract text from a document and pipe it into a new .Rmd file. I would only take this approach as a last resort and there are plenty of examples with a basic Google search for Sed or Awk. Best, Derek

Comment: I have a main Rmd file, in which I want to include other Rmd files depending on a given condition. 
For example (this would be the main Rmd):
    ```{r}  
    if(condition == T) {  
        source(purl("conditionalFile.Rmd", output = tempfile()), ...)  
    }  
   ```